# Access Azure DevOps API via OAuth 2.0 Azure AD

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-devops, odata, postman, azure-devops-rest-api

In postman i have set simple request to access Azure DevOps API, using OAuth 2.0 security via Azure AD
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
On Azure AD application setup with permission to acess Azure DevOps API with user consent

Im getting token, however  Azure DevOps API keeps returning code 203 with sign in html instead of json response. I would appreciate any suggestions

Thanks

Postman request

```
GET /[some_org]/_apis/projects?api=5.1 HTTP/1.1
Host: dev.azure.com 
Authorization: Bearer [something] 
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1 
Accept: */* 
Cache-Control: no-cache 
Postman-Token: [something] 
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate 
Cookie: VstsSession=[something] 
Referer: https://dev.azure.com/[some_org]/_apis/projects?api=5.1 
Connection: keep-alive cache-control: no-cache
```

[Token get details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zDnP.png)

Comment: Actually, using Azure DevOps API with AAD token is allowed. Here is a sample about c# code to do it.https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample/Program.cs

Answer (score 7):

1. I managed to replicate your issue using the OAuth 2.0
   authentication in Postman.
2. I started to look little more about the REST API for Azure DevOps
   and I found the document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

3. Few key parts:

> For Azure DevOps Services, instance is dev.azure.com/{organization},
>   so the pattern looks like this:

```
VERB https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis[/{area}]/{resource}?api-version={version}
```

> If you wish to provide the personal access token through an HTTP
>   header, you must first convert it to a Base64 string (the following
>   example shows how to convert to Base64 using C#). (Certain tools like
>   Postman applies a Base64 encoding by default. If you are trying the
>   API via such tools, Base64 encoding of the PAT is not required).

```
Authorization: Basic BASE64PATSTRING
```

4. I configured my postman to use GET Request and Basic Authentication (and it worked)

   GET http://dev.azure.com/{organization-id}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1

[image: GET Request]

[image: Basic Authentication]

[image]

More information about Personal Access Token for Azure DevOps REST API is available
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

PS
And here is page regarding Azure DevOps REST API and OAuth 2.0 Authentication
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops)
There is information on how to register your application to generate OAuth 2.0 credentials required to authorize.

Comment: Please, correct me if im wrong, but you are using basic autorization, same time as i need to use OAuth 2.0 security via Azure AD (please, check Token get details attached). I did try initially to use same link as you suggested, but no luck. Thank you

Comment: I just want to confirm, did you recevie Access Token using "Get New Access Token" (by providing Callback URL, Auth URL, Access Token URL etc... ) ?

Comment: I think she is using the post man tool to get an access token via oauth and not using PAT so token should be passed as bearer.

@VictoriaPolupan are you doing that ?once you receive the token are you passing it as authorization header. Also if the authentication has been failed it should return 401 and not 203. Also what is the postman-token in your request is it same as the token? check if you have all the parameters right

Comment: if you put PAT into access token field in postman (with OAuth 2 type authentication) you get 203 error.

Comment: @Kamil, in regards to you question: yes, i received token returned from "Get new access token" call  (details i'm using to get token provided under Token get details image attached to this post)

Comment: @biswpo, yes im using Oauth2 to get token from Azure AD as per post information and i'm not using PAT that could be issued for specific user on Azure DevOps profile.  As per Postman request sample added to post, im including token returned from  "Get new access token" call as  Authorization: Bearer [token].

Comment: @VictoriaPolupan I think you can't authorize to Azure DevOps API using Azure AD. The only two methods are PAT and Oauth App Registration (example https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops)

Comment: @Kamil, MS docs: "The following guidance is intended for Azure DevOps Services users, since OAuth 2.0 is not supported on Team Foundation Server or Azure DevOps Server" (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops) and also @"Azure DevOps Services is the cloud offering \ Azure DevOps Server is the on-premises offering" (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops). Following those 2 links,  OAuth 2.0 is supported for Cloud deployment and not support for on-premises.

Comment: That's correct. OAuth 2.0 is type of authentication and Azure AD is one of it's implementation.

Comment: Did you register your application/postman on https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/app/register to receive credentials for OAuth 2.0 type authentication for Azure Devops API? (this is different from Azure AD)

Comment: To use a PAT token, instead of setting the Authorization header manually, go to the Authorization tab in Postman and select "Basic Auth" as the authentication Type. Leave the username blank and paste the PAT token into the Password field.